# Check if an item exist on the list an print the item and othe fields that the item is in it

Tags: python

I am checking one file against another to see if the item that I am checking exist on both files. If the item exists in I want to print out the item and the row that the item is present on it. At the moment I can only print the items exist in both files 10366 and 51954. how to i print the whole row.

for example:
if the POS value exists in file one and files two, I want to print

```
1   10366   rs58108140  G   A   
1   51954   rs185832753 G   C
```

file one

```
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    
1   10366   rs58108140  G   A   
1   10611   rs189107123 C   G   
1   51954   rs185832753 G   C   
1   13327   rs144762171 G   C   
1   13957   .   TC  T   28  
1   13980   rs151276478 T   C
```

file two

```
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    
1   10366   rs58108140  G   A   
1   51935   rs181754315 C   T   
1   51954   rs185832753 G   C   
1   52058   rs62637813  G   C   
1   52144   rs190291950 T   A   
1   52238   rs150021059 T   G   
1   54353   rs140052487 C   A
```

```
def test():
  d= allel.vcf_to_recarray("merged_Small.vcf")
  c=d['POS']

  df = allel.vcf_to_recarray("FamilyVarient.txt")
  d=df['POS']

  for a in d:
      if a in c:
          print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not worried about optimization, you could always make a simple bash script that greps file 2 for each POS in file 1.